# p:autocomplete stops working after updating parent via ajax

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete, jsf-2.2

I have a list of autocompletes that is rendered using a `p:dataList`. Something like shown below:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="outerPanel">
    <p:dataList rendered="#{bean.myModel.listOfItems.size()>0}"
                var="additionalMP"
                value="#{bean.myModel.listOfItems}" 
                rowIndexVar="index" emptyMessage="">
         <div class="wrapper ui-g">
            <div>
              <p:autoComplete
                          cache="true"
                          value="#{bean.myModel.listOfItems[index]}"  
                          completeMethod ="#{handler.getAutoCompleteData}"
                          rendered ="true"
                          required="false"
                          scrollHeight="200"
                          styleClass="custom"
                          forceSelection="true"> 
                   <p:ajax event="query" global="false"/>    
                   <f:attribute name="filter" value="filterName" /> 
                   <f:attribute name="mode" value="edit" />                          
              </p:autoComplete>                            
             </div>
            <div>                                                    
               <p:commandLink value="+ Add" actionListener="#{bean.addAutoComplete()}" 
                    update=":formName:outerPanel"></p:commandLink>
            </div>
          </div>
     </p:dataList>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So, the `Add` button inserts a new item in the list and I update the container panel so that the newly added item can be rendered on the UI.

As expected the panel is updated and I see another autocomplete on the UI. But the problem is, all the auto completes now don't work. i.e. they stop firing the query event and don't give any suggestions.

Edited: The partial response that updates the section of form with autocomplete fields, contains some script tags, which probably execute on page ready/load event. So I know that basically the newly added prime faces widgets are not being initialized.

Any idea how I can initialize the newly added autocompletes in the DOM?

Comment: Please make it into a [mcve]. And tried the latest PF (just for this) and what is your jsf version and impl?

Comment: Upgrading to the latest PF version is not possible. It is a maintenance project

Comment: Can't be, you are developing new functionality

Comment: Yes. enhancing an existing application. But can't upgrade

Comment: And what if you make a little separated new JSF project and try to make the same but with PrimeFaces 6.1?

Comment: will be doing that soon

Comment: Where is the [mcve]? |And the version info... It is **impossible** to help

Comment: So you are requesting us to help with an old and unknown PF version and a missing [mcve]. Kind of impossible.Oh and _"Something like shown below:"_ does not help either.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive AND http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ AND missing version info!

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry was on vacation, couldn't respond. So, I am creating this Minimal example on a fresh page from scratch and it works as expected. There is something definitely wrong with the huge form that I have on the original problem area. Once I know what's wrong I will post an answer. It might be a silly error eventually.

Comment: Ok, vacation is always good. Only not great to award a bounty at the same time...

Comment: Yeah, will keep that in mind the next time

Answer (score 1):

The reason for all this trouble was an error in `javascript` that was caused by trying to `scrollTo` a particular element on the page from the bean. This crappy line of code in the bean was the source of all the trouble. There was no element on the page with the id `messages`. A glaring example of why UI should not be coupled in such a way.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().scrollTo("formId:messages");
```

Comment: No, not really or not 'only'... For me also a glaring example of that basic debugging is needed, always which includes creating a [mcve]. But great it works...

Comment: @Kukeltje trust me that much more than basic debugging was done. But yes creating a fresh example from the start would have saved a lot of pain. Appreciate your time and acknowledge your point of creating a minimal example